# Using disabled, ngModel and ngModelChanged bindings together throws an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-material2, rxjs6

*Please see the sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvcrcz*

I have `<mat-checkbox [ngModel]="row.IsVerified" [disabled]="row.IsVerified" (ngModelChange)="setTrue()"></mat-checkbox>` in my template.

The `setTrue` method looks like this:

  `setTrue = () => {
    ObservableOf(67).subscribe(_ => {
      this.row.IsVerified = true; // This throws a ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError!!!
    });
  }`

What I'm trying to achieve is: clicking the checkbox **should not immediately change the ngModel value**, but instead it should trigger a call to a server (to update the value on the server) and, upon succesful response code, set the `ngModel` to `true`.

Setting `ngModel` should, in turn, disable the checkbox to disallow the user to click it again.

However, I'm getting an error (in the console) saying: `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-untouched: true'. Current value: 'ng-untouched: false'.`

What should I do to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the binding on your HTML :

```
<mat-checkbox [disabled]="row.IsVerified" (ngModelChange)="setTrue()"></mat-checkbox>
```

Understand this : the data binding triggers a change detection. What happens is that you trigger that change detection when you click on the checkbox, then you run a function with `ngModelChange` that updates the variable.

Again, this triggers a change detection, and Angular checks the expression again, and see that is has changed : it throws an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

You're basically doing the same job twice, creating the issue.

#### EDIT Following the comments on that answer, the solution would be

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="!!row.isVerified" [disabled]="row.IsVerified" (ngModelChange)="setTrue()"></mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: Hm, but why is that so? My `[ngModel]` binding is a one-way binding, so clicking the checkbox by itself does not change the ngModel-bound value

Comment: Also, I need the checkbox to be initially checked/unchecked depending on the initial value of `row.IsVerified`

Comment: And how does angular know when to change the value of that input ? It still has to run a change detection ! And I told you you're doing the same thing twice, change the value of the variable only once, either through the binding or by the function, but not both.

Comment: Okay, how would you suggest me to do that? The requirements are these:
1. Checkbox should have an initial value based on the bound value.
2. Checkbox should update its value based on changes in the bound value.
3. The checkbox should be disabled whenever the bound value is true.
4. The setTrue() hadler should be fired whenever the user clicks the checkbox (if it's enabled)

Comment: The easiest and fastest way for you would to simply remove the variable setting in your function. The binding will take care of setting the value of your variable. So remove `this.row.isVerified = true` and you should be good

Comment: But I need to update the `IsVerified` value only **after** I've received a successful response code

Comment: Then you remove the binding and you use html to set it to true.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you please give an example?

Comment: `<mat-checkbox checked [disabled]="row.IsVerified" (ngModelChange)="setTrue()"></mat-checkbox>`

Comment: okay, and how do I do this: 1. Checkbox should have an initial value based on the bound value

Comment: `[checked]="!!boundValue"`

Comment: hm, indeed, that might be a solution! Could you please update your anwser so that I can accept it?

Comment: Sorry, was in a meeting, I made an edit at the end of my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171329/discussion-between-maksym-and-trichetriche).